# How to extract zip file using powershell script on windows server 2012

Tags: powershell

Extract the zip file through powershell,I am using below script. But i got this error message

```
 Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Expand-Archive : The module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive' could not be loaded. For more
information, run 'Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive'.
At C:\windowsagentinstall.ps1:34 char:1
+ Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Expand-Archive -Path ApplicareSingleAgentWindows.Zi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...\Expand-Archive:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
```

This is my script

```
echo "Downloading Applicare SingleAgent Installer ..."

#This will hide the progress bar. If the progress bar is enabled it will slow the download process
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $env:PROTOCOL"://"$env:IP":"$env:PORT/applicare/standalone?userId=$env:USERID"&"filename=ApplicareSingleAgentWindows.zip -OutFile $pwd\ApplicareSingleAgentWindows.zip

echo "Download Complete"
try {
    $scriptPath = $PSScriptRoot
    if (!$scriptPath)
    {
        if ($psISE)
        {
            $scriptPath = Split-Path -Parent -Path $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath
        }
        else {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Cannot resolve script file's path"
            exit 1
        }
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Caught Exception: $($Error[0].Exception.Message)"
    exit 2
}
#echo "Current directory"
Write-Host "SingleAgent downloaded in Path: $scriptPath"

echo "Creating ApplicareSingleAgentWindows directory"
New-Item -Path 'ApplicareSingleAgentWindows' -ItemType Directory -Force

echo "Extracting ApplicareSingleagent zip file to ApplicareSingleAgentWindows directory"
Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Expand-Archive -Path ApplicareSingleAgentWindows.Zip -DestinationPath "$scriptPath\ApplicareSingleAgentWindows" -Force

Set-Location -Path "$scriptPath\ApplicareSingleAgentWindows"
```

I execute this "**Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive**" command but it didn't work , I got below error

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive' was not loaded because no valid module file was
found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFound
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I tried another command, I got same issue. **"Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive -RequiredVersion 1.2.5"**

```
PS C:\ApplicareSingleAgentWindows> Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive -RequiredVersion 1.2.5
Install-Module : The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive -RequiredVersion 1.2.5
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Install-Module:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Have you tried the installation options on this page:? https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive/1.2.5

Comment: I tried, but i got different error.

Comment: Can you confirm what version of PowerSHell you're using? The output from ```$PSVersionTable``` will contain all the details...

Comment: My powershell version is 4.0

Comment: I usually just call 7-Zip from my powershell scripts.

Comment: Can you please explain that (7-Zip)

Comment: Did you search this site for `powershell 7zip` at all?

Answer (score 0):

You state that you're using **PowerShell 4.0**.

- Seemingly, it doesn't come with the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive` module.
- It also doesn't come with the `PowerShellGet` module, so that you cannot use `Install-Module` to install it.

---

You have two options:

- *Either*: Install the `PowerShellGet` module, so as to make the [`Install-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PowershellGet/Install-Module) available to you, which enables you to install *any* module available from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/).

  - Doing so isn't trivial, however, and may require using [`Save-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PowershellGet/Save-Module) on a *PowerShell v5+* machine, from which you can copy the downloaded module to your v4 machine.
  - See the [official instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/install-on-older-systems).
- *Or*: Make direct use of .NET APIs - this *assumes that you have .NET Framework 4.5 or higher installed*:

  ```bash
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression, System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

  # Note: Be sure to use *full* paths, because .NET's working dir.
  #       usually differs from PowerShell's.
  [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory(
    (Convert-Path -LiteralPath ApplicareSingleAgentWindows.Zip),
    "$scriptPath\ApplicareSingleAgentWindows",
    $true
  )
  ```